# Prevent specific ip from using vpn

Tags: vpn

I had run a vpn on my ubuntu system. I want to force my system to not use that vpn for specific ip like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, so that for this specific ip connecting to vpn or not has no difference.

Comment: This depends on your VPN, and if the other side of the VPN allows "shared networks".

Comment: It is a ssh tunnel to my server and I have full access to the server.